# Defining custom widget style using SWT's style property

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Each Composite (View) in SWT can be specified with a set of predefined SWT styles.

I want to create a custom set of widgets and want to reuse style property for custom styles supported by these widgets.

E.g. I want to define something like

```
ObjectView extends Composite {
    OV_SHOW_NAME = 1 < 10001;
    OV_GRADIENT_BOTTOM = 1 < 10002;

    public ObjectView(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
    }
}
```

The view is supposed to be created as

```
view = new ObjectView(parent, ObjectView.OV_SHOW_NAME | ObjectView.OV_GRADIENT_BOTTOM);
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to reuse style property for custom widget styles according to SWT blue prints (didn't find it on the net).
2. What value space is available to define custom style values?